# Why did my Crassula Ovata sprout a new plant from the middle of the leaf?

Tags: succulents, germination, damage, sprouting

Check out what I found on my Carssula Ovata this morning:

[image]

And the back side:

[image]

The leaf looks dry/dead because the plant suffered a severe burn from staying in a closed greenhouse in early spring (about 5 months ago).

I guess the new plant sprouted in the middle of the leaf due to some interesting process related to the tissue damage. Have you ever seen anything like that? How is it even possible?

Comment: It is not in middle of the leave. The bottom part is dead, so now the living part think it hit soil, and so it start a new branch/plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/crassula) the Jade Plant is a member of a special family of plants that are able to "seemingly mature cells at leaf margins or leaf surface resume meristematic activity and the products differentiate into root, stem, and leaf". Drying out completely, whether as a result of deliberate pulling or cutting or damage as in this case, seems to trigger this behaviour. This is a well known feature of the Jade plant and makes it one of the easiest plants to propagate, and, because it is light on water requirements, tends to survive being ignored for long periods. It helps gardeners feel successful.